# How do debug array_multisort warning

Tags: php, array-multisort

Sometimes I find the warning “Array sizes are inconsistent” in the logs, for the command `array_multisort()`.

This is my code:

```php
            $columns_1 = array_column($data, 'col1');
            $columns_2 = array_column($data, 'col2');
            $columns_3 = array_column($data, 'col3');
            array_multisort($columns_1, SORT_ASC, $columns_2, SORT_ASC, $columns_3, SORT_ASC, $data);
```

The content of the `$data`-variable is fetched from an remote api.

I expect the reason for the error, is that the remote data sometimes is wrong/corrupted.

Is there any method to “catch” when there is a warning in `array_multisort()`?

I have tried to check for if all the arrays are of the same size and if not, not execute `array_multisort`, but that does not prevent the warning.

Comment: _"I have tried to check for if all the arrays are of the same size and if not, not execute array_multisort, but that does not prevent the warning."_ - you must have done it _wrong_ somehow then, because that you get a warning from a function that you did not even call, is quite impossible.

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

For to catch all general errors in php you can handle with Throwable exception method:

```php
try{
    // Maybe, any error will happen here
    array_multisort($columns_1, SORT_ASC, $columns_2, SORT_ASC, $columns_3, SORT_ASC, $data);
}catch(\Throwable $exception){ 
  echo $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  The thing is, that "array_multisort" does not throw any exception or error, but only a warning. Therefore I am not able to catch the error.

Comment: Yes it is. Here you are. 